# Low rate with python Kafka consumer that reads from multiple topics

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a python consumer group with 50 consumers that consume from 10 topics with 10 partitions each.
The consumer group subscribes to all of the topics in which some of them have low throughput.
We have a low rate (300 msg/sec), but when we sent messages just for one topic, and all others are empty, we got a higher rate.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: can you add the python lib you are using? and also tag the lib you use. It looks for me the consumer threads/processes are far from 100, the total number of partitions, and round-robin does not switch fast enough

Answer (score 0):

You can tune Kafka performance be choosing the right message delivery guarantees: at most once, at least once or exactly once. Give as more details about what delivery guarantees you are using and whats the number of topics/partition a consumer subscribe and also the replication factor for each topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MihaiGhita, we have 10 topics with 10 partitions for each.
The topics and partitions distribute evenly between the consumers.
In addition, we set the min.in-sync replica to 2 and the delivery guarantee is at least once